# call function on clicking stopsharing in google chrome while sharing a screen

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome

how to call a function when click on stop sharing button which appears bottom of chrome when sharing the screen.
I am building a screen recording app but as soon as i click on stop screen sharing, it stops sharing the screen but recording continues. I want to call function which is responsible to stop recording on click stop screen sharing

Comment: Can you post some code so we can see what you have tried?

Comment: I don't know if this thing exist or not. I want to know if it is possible to call a function on clicking stop sharing